Spring cloud contract - consumer side
i'm sorry but i'm new in Spring Cloud Contract.
I don't think I fully understand how it works and its usefulness.
The examples I have found always show specific contracts that do not use regular expressions but constants
The examples I have found always show specific contracts that do not use regular expressions but constants
I wrote a generic contract using regexes because I want to create patterns for all requests and returned data, this is my contract.groovy :

    > Contract.make {
    >     description "Should return the player in the team with best scores"
    >     request {
    >         method GET()
    >         url(regex("/player/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/bestPlayer"))
    >     }
    >     response {
    >         status 200
    >         headers {
    >             contentType(applicationJson())
    >         }
    >         body(
    >                 name      : $(anyNonEmptyString()),
    >                 role      : $(regex("(Forward|Midfielder|Defender|Goalkeeper)")),
    >                 age       : $(anyPositiveInt()),
    >                 goals     : $(anyPositiveInt()),
    >                 team      : $(anyNonEmptyString()),
    >                 gender    : $(anyOf('Male','Female')),
    >                 height    : $(anyPositiveInt()),
    >                 weight    : $(anyPositiveInt()),
    >                 injuries : [
    >                         [
    >                                 year :$(regex("[1-9][0-9]{3}")),
    >                                 type: $(anyNonEmptyString())
    >                         ]
    >                 ],
    >                 oldTeams : [
    >                         [
    >                                 year :$(regex("[1-9][0-9]{3}")),
    >                                 team: $(anyNonEmptyString())
    >                         ]
    >                 ]
    >                 )
    >     } }


To verify that my consumer respects the contract, I need to ensure that each request of type/player/{teamName}/bestPlayer returns a confirmation object to the contract.
In the file GetBestTeamPlayer.json I have a request of the type /player/‘sometext’/bestPlayer.
So I am wondering how can I ensure that the consumer fulfils the contract for each request?
Thanks in advance :)
